# Removing tables with a join in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, multiple-tables, deduplication

I'm new to this DBA thing and I've been tasked with removing duplicates from a couple of tables.  I'm working in SQL Server.  They all have a field called LAST_UPD that tracks their last update.  All the tables join to TABLE1 and each user is identified by TABLE1.ALIAS_KEY.  The join is below.  I'm wondering how to clean out all the duplicate rows and keep the most recent entries from Table2.  Thanks for the help!

```
FROM dbo.Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN dbo.Table2 T2
    ON (T1.PARROW = T2.PARROW)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming (and I might be incorrect) that last updated is unique you can do:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.Table2 T2 WHERE T2.LAST_UPD NOT IN
    (SELECT max(LAST_UPD) FROM dbo.Table2 T2 
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Table1 T1 ON (T1.PARROW = T2.PARROW)
        GROUP BY T1.ALIAS_KEY)
```

Comment: You assume correctly.  That should work out for me actually, thanks!